# Object oriented programming - C++ exercise

Tags: c++, oop, stack

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int pos=-1;
using namespace std; 

class StackElement { 
private: 
    int data; 
    string name; 
public: 
    StackElement() { 
        data=0;
        name="brak";
        } 
    StackElement(int d, string n) { 
        data = d;
        name = n;
        } 
    void getData() { 
        cin>>data;
        } 
    void getName() {
        cin>>name;
        } 
};
class Stack {
private: 
    int stackSize; 
    StackElement element[]; 
    public:
    Stack() {
        stackSize = 0;
        cout<<"Stack is empty now."<<endl;
        }
    Stack(int s) {
        stackSize = s;
        }
    void push() {
        element[pos+1].getData();
        cout<<"Enter element name:"<<endl;
        element[pos+1].getName();
        pos++;
        }
    void pop() {
        pos--;
        }
    bool isEmpty() {
        if(stackSize==0)
             return true;
        }
    bool isFull() {
        if(pos==MAX_SIZE)
             return true;
        }
 }; 
int main() {
    Stack stack(MAX_SIZE);
    int choice;
    cout<<"1. Push in stack.\n2. Pop from stack.\n3. Display stack.\n4. Exit."<<endl;
    if(stack.isEmpty())
        cout<<endl<<"Stack is empty."<<endl<<endl;
    do { 
        cout<<"Enter your choice"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                 cout<<"Enter value:"<<endl;
                 stack.push();
                 break;
            case 2:
                 stack.pop();
                 break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Soon-to-be displayer"<<endl;
                 break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"Exit"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid choice"<<endl;
        }
        if(stack.isFull()) {
            cout<<"Stack is full!"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
return 0; 
}
```

The exercise goes like this:
Create class Stack and StackElement.
Stack Element has to contain: 2 private pools of one choice, getter/getters and 2 constructors - default one and parameterized one (with 2 parameters).
Stack has to contain: elements of StackElement type, private pool *size*, one default and one parameterized (one parameter) constructor, methods *push, pop, isEmpty, isFull*

My problem is that when I run the program it crashes just after I try to put an element on the stack.

Comment: Please debug your code and note the exact line where your code crashes. Also add the input that creates the problem.

Comment: C-style array has static size. It will not resize itself. Use `std::vector` for resizeable array or declare size of your array upfront (and notify user when the maximum size is reached).

Comment: Turn up the warnings in your compiler.  If using gcc/clang use `-pedantic-errors`.  `StackElement element[]; ` should not compile as no size was provided.

Comment: Do you want to implement your stack using stl containers or do you want to implement the memory management yourself? You can use dynamic array or a dynamic list.

Answer (score 2):

The `push` function starts with

```
element[pos+1].getData();
```

`pos` is a global variable, starting at -1, so this will be 0 to begin with.
You need to see what size your stack is, before trying to get data from elements that are not there.

`StackElement element[];` needs to be resized or declare it like this:

```
StackElement element[MAX_SIZE];
```

Comment: I declared it like you suggested, but now I can't add more than 1 element to the stack.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Ask another question, showing how you are calling this and what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I figured it out. If anyone ever needed similar thing to see to, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class StackElement {
private:
    int data;
    string name;
public:
    StackElement() {
        data=0;
        name="-";
        }
    StackElement(int d, string n) {
        data = d;
        name = n;
        }
    void getElement() {
        cin>>data;
        cout<<"Enter name: "<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        }
};
class Stack {
private:
    int stackSize;
    int pos;
    StackElement *element;
public:
    Stack() {
        stackSize = 10;
        element = new StackElement[stackSize];
        }
    Stack(int s) {
        stackSize = s;
        element = new StackElement[stackSize];
        }
    void push() {
        element[pos++].getElement();
        ++stackSize;
        }
    StackElement pop() {
        return element[--pos];
        }
    bool isEmpty() {
        return pos == 0;
        }
    bool isFull() {
        return stackSize == pos;
        }
    void position() {
        pos=0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Stack stack(10);
    stack.position();
    int choice;
    cout<<"1. Push in stack.\n2. Pop from stack.\n3. Exit."<<endl;
    if(stack.isEmpty())
        cout<<endl<<"Stack is empty."<<endl<<endl;
    do {
        cout<<"Enter your choice"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Enter value:"<<endl;
                stack.push();
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    cout<<"Stack is empty already."<<endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"Exit"<<endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid choice"<<endl;
        }
        if(stack.isFull()) {
            cout<<"Stack is full!"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
return 0;
}
```

PS. I know it lacks freeing memory and a destructor, I might work on it in near future :)

Comment: Having the `pos` and stack size locally seems sensible. Do you know why you couldn't push back more than one element before?